# Android How to get last user response time

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know if the user is away for some amount of time. (and then do something according to it.)
 I cannot depent on screen sleep because user may have disabled it or its value may be greater than timeout of my application.

**is there any information like (last user response time ) in android operation system ? and how can i get it?**

last user response time  = the last interraction time between the user and the phone.

p.s.:i am targetting android 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to tell when was the last time the user interacted with your application in  the SDK. You'll have to do something by yourself.

---

**High level explanation of a simple solution:**

Assuming you use some base activity inherited by all activities, you can log the current time in your BaseActivity.onPause method. Save it in the app preferences or in a database. When your initial activity starts (onResume) read the same value and compare it the current time.

You can also use [Activity.onUserInteraction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction) but saving to preferences/database everytime this is called will considerably slow down your app / feel less responsive!

Comment: i am already doing that but what if user stays on the same activity for a long time while screen sleep is disabled.in that case i wont be able to know that user is away.

Comment: but how could you tell if the user was looking at your screen or not? You can also use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction() but saving to preferecens/database everytime this is called will considerably slow down your app / feel less responsive!

Comment: if you edit your answer with your latest comment i will accept it.